# При использование jquery выходит ошибка Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Я решил сделать форму,которая отправляет данные через ajax, но в консоли браузера выходит следующая ошибка:
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

```
$('#contactButton').on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
      let department = $('#Department').val();
      let id = $('#id').val();
      let date_of_registration=$('#Date_of_registration').val();
      let order_number_and_date=$('#Order_number_and_date').val();
      let fio=$('#FIO').val();
      let hospital_card=$('#Hospital_card').val();
      let area_of_residence=$('#Area_of_residence').val();
      let residential_address=$('#residential_address').val();
      let date_of_birth=$('#Date_of_birth').val();
      let passport=$('#Passport').val();
      let pinfl=$('#PINFL').val();
      let phone=$('#Phone').val();
      let date_of_admission=$('#Date_of_admission').val();
      let date_of_discharge=$('#Date_of_discharge').val();
      let the_main_diagnosis=$('#The_main_diagnosis').val();
      let name_of_the_diagnosis=$('#Name_of_the_diagnosis').val();
      let concomitant_diagnosis=$('#Concomitant_diagnosis').val();
      let symptoms=$('#Symptoms').val();
      let payment_Information=$('#Payment_Information').val();
      let type_of_benefit=$('#Type_of_benefit').val();
      let complaints=$('#complaints').val();
      let previously=$('#previously_eceived_treatment').val();
      let medical_history=$('#medical_history').val();
      let accompanying_illnesses=$('#accompanying_illnesses').val();
      let past_illnesses=$('#past_illnesses').val();
      let allergic_reactions=$('#allergic_reactions').val();
    $.ajax({
          url: "/registration",
          type:"POST",
          data:{
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            id:id,
            date_of_registration:date_of_registration,
            department:department,
            order_number_and_date:order_number_and_date,
            fio:fio,
            hospital_card:hospital_card,
            area_of_residence:area_of_residence,
            residential_address: residential_address,
            date_of_birth:date_of_birth,
            passport:passport,
            pinfl:pinfl,
            phone:phone,
            date_of_admission:date_of_admission,
            date_of_discharge:date_of_discharge,
            the_main_diagnosis:the_main_diagnosis,
            name_of_the_diagnosis:name_of_the_diagnosis,
            concomitant_diagnosis:concomitant_diagnosis,
            symptoms:symptoms,
            payment_Information:payment_Information,
            type_of_benefit:type_of_benefit,
            previously_eceived_treatment:previously_eceived_treatment,
            medical_history:medical_history,
            accompanying_illnesses:accompanying_illnesses,
            past_illnesses:past_illnesses,
            allergic_reactions:allergic_reactions,
          },
    success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
            $( "#popup-registration" ).last().removeClass( "display" );
          },
         });
        });
    
    const containerAdd = $('#tbody')
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET', 
            url: '/patients',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                containerAdd.html('');
               
                    containerAdd.html(''); 
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                 
    
    containerAdd.append('<tr><td>'+ item.FIO + '</td><td>' + item.Date_of_birth + '</td><td>'+ item.The_main_diagnosis+'</td><td>'+ item.Phone+'</td><td>'+item.Area_of_residence+'</td><td>'+paymentStatus(item.Payment_Information)+'</td><td><img class="group-image"><button class="group-image__button"><a class="link" href="form-registration/' + item.id+ '")><img src="{{asset("images/eye-fill.svg")}}" class="group-image__icon"></a></button><button class="group-image__button"><a class="link" href="edit/' + item.id+ '")><img src="{{asset("images/pen-fill.svg")}}" id="pen" class="group-image__icon"></a></button> <form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/patients/' + item.id+'") }}" method="POST">{!! csrf_field() !!}{!! method_field("DELETE") !!}<button class="group-image__button"><img src="{{asset("images/trash.svg")}}" class="group-image__icon"></td></button></form></tr>' );
                   
                    
              });
             
            },error:function(){ 
                 console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: пишите так: `previously_eceived_treatment:previously_eceived_treatment,` а тут вот так `let previously=$('#previously_eceived_treatment').val();` может нужно так? `previously_eceived_treatment:previously`

Comment: с пробросом параметров с формы в аякс вообще дич какая-то. Вы не устали писать вот эти вот все имена переменных? А потом ими заполнять объект? Можно ведь наверное, как минимум, не объявлять переменные, а сразу в объект вписать данные полей? А как максимум, поля, формы которые требуется отправлять, пометить классом, по  нему сформировать объект. А если отправлять надо все, то вообще сериализовать форму.

Comment: а вообще ошибка о том, что у вас там вероятно рекурсия